# Internet works in bursts on osx?

Tags: macos, internet

When I use internet on my mac on chrome, all websites keep spinning and after some seconds all of them start getting data at a high speed. What can be the reason?

This only happens with my internet at home. 
It happens most of the time in chrome and many times in safari also, although not every time like chrome

version:OSX snow leopard

Comment: does this happen when you first start the computer? first start chrome? will it happen all day long?

Comment: Does this happen regardless of the network you are on? Do you see the same behavior in Safari? Ditto what @Logman has asked as well.

Comment: What version of OS X?